# Aplicar o SyntheticaBlackEyeLookAndFeel na aplicação

Tags: java, swing

Gostaria de saber como posso aplicar novos *look and feel*s que não fazem parte do JDK. Na tentativa de aplicar, está dando um erro no qual não encontrei uma resposta que pudesse resolver o problema.

Por Exemplo: O *Synthetica Classy Look and Feel*:

Classe de Teste:

```
import de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaBlackEyeLookAndFeel;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class JavaApplication12 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaBlackEyeLookAndFeel());
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException | ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }        
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Teste");
}

}
```

Descrição do erro:

> reference to setLookAndFeel is ambiguous   both method
>   setLookAndFeel(LookAndFeel) in UIManager and method
>   setLookAndFeel(String) in UIManager match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo o [**site oficial**](http://www.jyloo.com/synthetica/faq/#general-1) e como pode ser visto [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14333324/5524514), a forma correta de aplicar é a que segue:

```
try {

  UIManager.setLookAndFeel("de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaBlackEyeLookAndFeel");

} catch (Exception e) {

  e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Lembrando que deve-se adicionar também o [**synthetica.jar**](http://www.jyloo.com/synthetica/download/) no classpath, além do jar do tema baixado(no seu caso, o *syntheticaBlackEye.jar*) antes de fazer esta chamada, conforme pode ser visto abaixo no print de exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ele executa conforme a look and feel metal, adicionei o jar baixado na biblioteca...

Comment: Será que pode ser a versão do NetBeans, ele não encontra a a classe. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/javasoft/plaf/synthetica/SyntheticaLookAndFeel

Comment: @UlissesGimenes editei com uma informação adicional, por favor tente seguir a novas orientações da resposta.

Comment: Deu certo, agradeço pela ajuda, não tinha importado o synthetica..